# Angular routerLink in route with path doesnt route

Tags: angular

Hello this is my route

```
  {
    path: 'product/:title/:option',
    component: ProductComponent
  },
```

and routerLink

```
 [routerLink]="['/product/'+title]+'/'+option"
```

but whenever im on component lets say 'product/title/option'
and i want to route to 'product/anotherTitle/anotherOption', link in search bar is being changed, but content stay how it is...
What am i able to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't re-render the component when you are on the same routing path. You have to watch the params change in the component and should update your component based on the params.

For example:

```js
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    // Update your content with `params.title` and `params.option`
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pass to `routerLink` parameters array https://angular.io/guide/router#link-parameters-array

In your case it will looks like:

`[routerLink]="['product', title, option]"`

Comment: same result, ty.